# LINQ find max/min value with corresponding time fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have a table of data recordings from a weather station from which I am querying results into a  WPF `ListBox`.

The table structure is:

- date
- time
- temp
- rain_today
- humidity
- etc

I have a query which works fine:

```
var q = from c in db.Apr11log
                group c by c.LogDate into g
                orderby g.Key
                select new
                {
                    LogDate = g.Key,
                    MaxTemp = g.Max(c => c.Temp),
                    MinTemp = g.Min(c => c.Temp),                                             
                    Rain = g.Max(c => c.Rain_today),
                };
```

However I am trying to get the corresponding time of the Max Temp and Min Temp, i.e.

```
TimeMax = .....
TimeMin = .....
```

I've googled and googled but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let maxTemp = c.Max(c=>c.Temp)
let minTemp = c.Min(c=>c.Temp)
select new {
    LogDate = g.Key,
    MaxTemp = maxTemp,
    MinTemp = minTemp,
    MaxTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Temp = maxTemp).Time,
    MinTime = g.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Temp = minTemp).Time,
    Rain = g.Max(c => c.Rain_today),
       };
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. However I cannot get any of them to work.  I don't think I made myself clear though. I was after the corresponding LogTime (in the same row) of the Daily Max and Min temperatures, which are obtained through the Group by LogDate.

Answer (score 5):

```
var q = from c in db.Apr11log
        group c by c.LogDate into g
        orderby g.Key
        select new
        {
            LogDate = g.Key,
            MaxRow = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Temp).Select(c => new { c.LogDate, c.Temp }).First(),
            MinRow = g.OrderBy(c => c.Temp).Select(c => new { c.LogDate, c.Temp }).First(),
            Rain = g.Max(c => c.Rain_today),
        };
```

or

```
var q = from c in db.Apr11log
        group c by c.LogDate into g
        orderby g.Key
        let maxRow = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Temp).First()
        let minRow = g.OrderBy(c => c.Temp).First()
        select new
        {
            LogDate = g.Key,
            MaxTemp = maxRow.Temp,
            MaxTempDate = maxRow.LogDate,
            MinTemp = minRow.Temp,
            MinTempDate = minRow.LogDate,
            Rain = g.Max(c => c.Rain_today),
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alex, this works well.  Just had to change LogDate to LogTime :-)